# SQL Server primary key error

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I am designing a web-based logistics system using ASP.NET and SQL Server.

In one of my classes when I try to insert data to database, there is a violation of primary key error, but data inserts successfully into the table. I can not find out where the problem is. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
public int fillShipmentDetail()
{
   int success = 0;
   string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LGDB"].ToString();

   SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

   SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("fillShipmentDetails", sqlCon);
   sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   sqlCon.Open();

   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("shipOrderID", ShipOrderID);
   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("totalWeight", TotalWeight);
   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("weightIsMetric", WeightUnit);
   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("weightIsImperial", VolumeUnit);
   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("volume", Volume);
   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("quantity", Quantity);
   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", Value);
   sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", GoodsDescription);            

   success = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

   if (success == 1)
   {
      success = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      success = 0;
   }            

   sqlCon.Close();            
   return success;
}
```

`aspx.cs` page

```
 Classes.ShipmentDetails fillShipmentDetails = new Classes.ShipmentDetails(
                getLastShipOrder, _weight, _checkMetricImperial_weight, _checkMetricImperial_volume,
                _volume, _quantity, _value, txtGoodsDescription.Text);
            int success3 = fillShipmentDetails.fillShipmentDetail();
```

[image]

As you can see in the below picture the record shipOrderID 7192 is already inserted into the table.

[image]

I have deleted all three tables , and insert new data. although data inserts successfully but error happens again.[image]

this screenshot shows everything clearly , by every new insertion into database there is a primary key error on last table , as you can see there is not any duplicate key and data inserted successfully.
[image]

Comment: What does `getLastShipOrder` do? How do you determine the next ship order ID ??

Comment: the shipOrderID for this table comes from another table, data gathered from three different table.

Comment: and this becomes your primary key? Can you be ***1000% SURE*** that you're not creating duplicates here??

Comment: the primary key in this table come from an auto generated primary key of another table, every time user inserts data an index is generated automatically ,so it can not be duplicate, i will insert more data now and put screen shot, so u can see there is no duplicate. i am really surprised because it was just working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like fillShipmentDetails.fillShipmentDetail() is getting fired twice.  Put a Breakpoint in the code and check

Comment: Also check your stored procedure

Comment: I've checked the method , it only called once, also stored procedure executes successfully.

Comment: Remove the primary key from the table and check if the values gets inserted twice

Comment: i removed primary key in the table. after insertion i saw each record inserts 4 times in table. then i have noticed there was a foreach loop before i make a connection to database ,that i did not close it!!!! so every operation repeated for four times!!!

Answer (score 1):

`shipOrderId` already exists in your table.

You need to give it a new unique value.  The reason why the table updates is because the `shipOrderId` already exists, so you can create a new `Shipping Order` with the Id, however that order is not referring to the correct `shipOrderId`

Comment: it does not exits , for every new insertion this error happens!

Comment: @AlirezaX - it does exist, I can see it in your screenshot (7192)

Comment: it's auto generated , it can not be duplicate ,

Comment: i take this screenshot after insert , it inserts the new value , but also throw primary key error

Comment: @AlirezaX - is your function being called twice?

Comment: ,i don't think so, i checked it, it was working 5 minutes ago, before I've entered data so many time without any problem!

Comment: Is it possible that the problem realtes to trigger recursion , because last night one of my stored procedure went inoto loop and i inset this command to fix it:   ALTER DATABASE databasename
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON | OFF